# How to refresh <div> content faster on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, buttonclick

I have a  content with some value and on click of cancel button, I need to refresh that  and display the new content. When I click on cancel button, the old content stays for some seconds before changing to new content for that .Pls let me know how to load the new content faster without this delay.

```
<div>Text</div>

   <button type="button" class="left-btn pull-right" (click)="reload()" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>

 reload() {
    this.CommonService.GetDateTimeByTimeZone().subscribe(tz => {
      let ds: Input = {
        StartDate: moment(this.timezoneDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000[Z]"),
        EndDate: moment(this.timezoneDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59.999[Z]")
      }
      this.Dashboard(ds, false)
    }, error => {
      Swal.fire('', this.es.adminErrorMsgList[39].message, 'error')
    });
    this.SelectedDate = ' ';
  }
```

Comment: Are you retrieving the new content via `this.CommonService.GetDateTimeByTimeZone()`?

Comment: Yes..The content should display based on todays date

Comment: What is the roundtrip of your function call? The update depends on that

Comment: You are seemingly doing an async request inside your reload function. This is just how it works... it takes an unknown amount of time for the request to finish, you cannot really speed it up. Usually we show a spinner or something while we are waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
reload() {

   // do the reload here

    this.CommonService.GetDateTimeByTimeZone().subscribe(tz => {
      let ds: Input = {
        StartDate: moment(this.timezoneDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000[Z]"),
        EndDate: moment(this.timezoneDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59.999[Z]")
      }
      this.Dashboard(ds, false)
    }, error => {
      Swal.fire('', this.es.adminErrorMsgList[39].message, 'error')
    });
    this.SelectedDate = ' ';
  }
```

Comment: The code I wrote is the reload code.